# How do I handle the ',' in the sys.argv __name__ statement below

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

This is a little terminal journal app I am working on.

Intended functionality: type in terminal `python3 journal.py whatever note I want to keep, with commas included.` The entry 'whatever note I want to keep, with commas included' gets stored in a csv in a single cell.

Actual functionality: the note 'whatever note I want to keep, with commas included' is split into multiple cells on the ','. This problem was solved in the multi_stuff function but the same technique isn't working in the sys.argv[1:] in the **name** portion.

any thoughts?

```
import csv
import sys
import re
import datetime

def record(stuff):
    with open('journal.csv', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(datetime.datetime.now())+','+stuff+'\n')

def multi_line():
    while True:
        multi_stuff = input('Type "Q" to quit. Otherwise, talk to me -> ').lower()
        if ',' in multi_stuff:
            multi_stuff = multi_stuff.replace(',', '","')
        if multi_stuff == 'q':
            break
        with open('journal.csv', 'a') as f:
            f.write(str(datetime.datetime.now())+','+multi_stuff+'\n')


def search():
    keyword = input('search term -> ').lower()
    regex = r"\b(?=\w)" + re.escape(keyword) + r"\b(?!\w)"
    with open('journal.csv', 'r') as csv:
        for line in csv:
            if re.search(regex, line):
                print(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == '-s':
        search()
    elif sys.argv[1].lower() == '-m':
        multi_line()
    else:
        arg = sys.argv[1:]
        if ',' in arg:
            arg = arg.replace(',', '","')
            record(' '.join(arg))
        else:
            record(' '.join(arg))
```

Comment: Please show the erroneous output.

Comment: `',' in sys.argv[1:]` is only going to be true if one of the command-line arguments consists solely of a comma - in other words, spaces on both sides.  You might want to do the `' '.join(arg)` first, so that you only have to deal with a single string rather than a list.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll try it.

Comment: `    else:
        arg = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
        if ',' in arg:
            arg = arg.replace(',', '","')
            record(arg)
        else:
            record(' '.join(arg))`

Comment: totally worked!